# Fixed table header with dynamic content?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I've found several solutions for a fixed header, but none of them will fix my problem.

I have a table, styled with jQuery mobile (Responsive table). This table is dynamically filled with a `.append`. The columns don't have a fixed width, they vary.
 Is there a way, to fix the header of the table, so that I am able to scroll through the table body with the header always showing at the top, but without the use of multiple tables.

Summary:

I would like to have a single table with a fixed header.

I'm amazed that there is no standard for this, as I assume that this is something most webdevs can use. Please, correct me if I'm wrong.

Thank you in advance!

**Edit:**

Example:

```
<table id="my_id" data-role="table" class="ui-body-d ui-shadow table-stripe
 ui-responsive">
    <thead id="must_be_static">
       <tr>
          <th>This guy should be static</th>
          <th>This guy should be static</th>
          <th>This guy should be static</th>
          <th>This guy should be static</th>
          <th>This guy should be static</th>
       </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="id_for_content">
       <tr>
          <td>Dynamic content</td>
          <td>Dynamic content</td>
          <td>Dynamic content</td>
          <td>Dynamic content</td>
          <td>Dynamic content</td>
       </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
       <tr>
          <td>Foot</td>
          <td>Foot</td>
          <td>Foot</td>
          <td>Foot</td>
          <td>Foot</td>
       </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: There is no way to do this with a single table (at least to my knowledge), which is unfortunate as it muddies up the semantic relationship between table header cells and table data cells.

Comment: There's no way of doing this in HTML/CSS alone but you can use a jQuery plugin to handle it for you: http://fixedheadertable.com/

Comment: I tried to use the fixedheadertable plugin, but unfortunately, this transforms 1 table into 2 tables in the background. So not the solution I'm looking for..

Comment: post your code or reproduce the problem on fiddle.

Comment: Example given. Just your average table..

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking something like this::

http://jsfiddle.net/h5t98/

```
    <table border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="month">Month</th>
      <th class="saving">Savings</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td>Sum</td>
      <td>$180</td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>February</td>
      <td>$80</td>
    </tr>
      <tr>
      <td>January</td>
      <td>$100</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: That is not dinamyc, as soon as the content changes, the columns update the size but the headers stick to the same size, so it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the following http://www.datatables.net/extras/fixedheader/ will work for you?

Answer (score 0):

can u draw an example of what you are trying to do ? cause it sounds you have a css problem and not a jquery problem.

I think this is what you are looking for based on your summary, example bellow is pulled from another website "[googled exactly your tile](https://css-tricks.com/position-sticky-and-table-headers/)" which kind of categorizes as a standard. [tested in chrome 84.3 or whatever is the latest should work in all browsers since is just tabling attributes]

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 2rem;
}

table {
  text-align: left;
  position: relative;
  border-collapse: collapse; 
}
th, td {
  padding: 0.25rem;
}
tr.red th {
  background: red;
  color: white;
}
tr.green th {
  background: green;
  color: white;
}
tr.purple th {
  background: purple;
  color: white;
}
th {
  background: white;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr class="red">
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Job</th>
      <th>Color</th>
      <th>URL</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem.</td>
      <td>Ullam.</td>
      <td>Vel.</td>
      <td>At.</td>
      <td>Quis.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Quas!</td>
      <td>Velit.</td>
      <td>Quisquam?</td>
      <td>Rerum?</td>
      <td>Iusto?</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Voluptates!</td>
      <td>Fugiat?</td>
      <td>Alias.</td>
      <td>Doloribus.</td>
      <td>Veritatis.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Maiores.</td>
      <td>Ab.</td>
      <td>Accusantium.</td>
      <td>Ullam!</td>
      <td>Eveniet.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Hic.</td>
      <td>Id!</td>
      <td>Officiis.</td>
      <td>Modi!</td>
      <td>Obcaecati.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Soluta.</td>
      <td>Ad!</td>
      <td>Impedit.</td>
      <td>Alias!</td>
      <td>Ad.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Expedita.</td>
      <td>Quo.</td>
      <td>Exercitationem!</td>
      <td>Optio?</td>
      <td>Ipsum?</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Commodi!</td>
      <td>Rem.</td>
      <td>Aspernatur.</td>
      <td>Accusantium!</td>
      <td>Maiores.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Omnis.</td>
      <td>Cumque?</td>
      <td>Eveniet!</td>
      <td>Mollitia?</td>
      <td>Vero.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Error!</td>
      <td>Inventore.</td>
      <td>Quasi!</td>
      <td>Ducimus.</td>
      <td>Repudiandae!</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Dolores!</td>
      <td>Necessitatibus.</td>
      <td>Corrupti!</td>
      <td>Eum.</td>
      <td>Sunt!</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ea.</td>
      <td>Culpa?</td>
      <td>Quam?</td>
      <td>Nemo!</td>
      <td>Sit!</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Veritatis!</td>
      <td>Facilis.</td>
      <td>Expedita?</td>
      <td>Ipsam!</td>
      <td>Omnis!</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Vitae.</td>
      <td>Cumque.</td>
      <td>Repudiandae.</td>
      <td>Ut?</td>
      <td>Sed!</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Accusantium.</td>
      <td>Adipisci.</td>
      <td>Sit.</td>
      <td>Maxime.</td>
      <td>Harum.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="green">
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Job</th>
      <th>Color</th>
      <th>URL</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Qui!</td>
      <td>Accusamus?</td>
      <td>Minima?</td>
      <td>Dolorum.</td>
      <td>Molestiae.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Vero!</td>
      <td>Voluptatum?</td>
      <td>Ea?</td>
      <td>Odit!</td>
      <td>A.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Debitis.</td>
      <td>Veniam.</td>
      <td>Fuga.</td>
      <td>Alias!</td>
      <td>Recusandae!</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Aperiam!</td>
      <td>Dolorum.</td>
      <td>Enim.</td>
      <td>Sapiente!</td>
      <td>Suscipit?</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Consequuntur.</td>
      <td>Doloremque.</td>
      <td>Illum!</td>
      <td>Iste!</td>
      <td>Sint!</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Facilis.</td>
      <td>Error.</td>
      <td>Fugiat.</td>
      <td>At.</td>
      <td>Modi?</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Voluptatibus!</td>
      <td>Alias.</td>
      <td>Eaque.</td>
      <td>Cum.</td>
      <td>Ducimus!</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Nihil.</td>
      <td>Enim.</td>
      <td>Earum?</td>
      <td>Nobis?</td>
      <td>Eveniet.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Eum!</td>
      <td>Id?</td>
      <td>Molestiae.</td>
      <td>Velit.</td>
      <td>Minima.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sapiente?</td>
      <td>Neque.</td>
      <td>Obcaecati!</td>
      <td>Earum.</td>
      <td>Esse.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Nam?</td>
      <td>Ipsam!</td>
      <td>Provident.</td>
      <td>Ullam.</td>
      <td>Quae?</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Amet!</td>
      <td>In.</td>
      <td>Officia!</td>
      <td>Natus?</td>
      <td>Tempore?</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Consequatur.</td>
      <td>Hic.</td>
      <td>Officia.</td>
      <td>Itaque?</td>
      <td>Quasi.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Enim.</td>
      <td>Tenetur.</td>
      <td>Asperiores?</td>
      <td>Eos!</td>
      <td>Libero.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Exercitationem.</td>
      <td>Quidem!</td>
      <td>Beatae?</td>
      <td>Adipisci?</td>
      <td>Accusamus.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Omnis.</td>
      <td>Accusamus?</td>
      <td>Eius!</td>
      <td>Recusandae!</td>
      <td>Dolor.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Magni.</td>
      <td>Temporibus!</td>
      <td>Odio!</td>
      <td>Odit!</td>
      <td>Voluptatum?</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Eum.</td>
      <td>Animi!</td>
      <td>Labore.</td>
      <td>Alias!</td>
      <td>Fuga.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Quia!</td>
      <td>Quis.</td>
      <td>Neque?</td>
      <td>Illo.</td>
      <td>Ad.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Officiis.</td>
      <td>Exercitationem!</td>
      <td>Adipisci?</td>
      <td>Officiis?</td>
      <td>In?</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Voluptates?</td>
      <td>Voluptatum.</td>
      <td>Nihil.</td>
      <td>Totam?</td>
      <td>Quisquam!</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Soluta.</td>
      <td>Tempore!</td>
      <td>Cupiditate.</td>
      <td>Beatae.</td>
      <td>Perspiciatis.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Porro.</td>
      <td>Officia?</td>
      <td>Error.</td>
      <td>Culpa?</td>
      <td>Fugit.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Et?</td>
      <td>Nemo.</td>
      <td>Nisi?</td>
      <td>Totam!</td>
      <td>Voluptate.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Saepe?</td>
      <td>Vero.</td>
      <td>Amet?</td>
      <td>Illo!</td>
      <td>Laborum!</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="purple">
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Job</th>
      <th>Color</th>
      <th>URL</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Atque!</td>
      <td>Tenetur.</td>
      <td>Optio.</td>
      <td>Iure.</td>
      <td>Porro.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Atque.</td>
      <td>Alias.</td>
      <td>Doloremque.</td>
      <td>Velit.</td>
      <td>Culpa.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Placeat?</td>
      <td>Necessitatibus.</td>
      <td>Voluptate!</td>
      <td>Possimus.</td>
      <td>Nam?</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Illum!</td>
      <td>Quae.</td>
      <td>Expedita!</td>
      <td>Omnis.</td>
      <td>Nam.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Consequuntur!</td>
      <td>Consectetur!</td>
      <td>Provident!</td>
      <td>Consequuntur!</td>
      <td>Distinctio.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Aperiam!</td>
      <td>Voluptatem.</td>
      <td>Cupiditate!</td>
      <td>Quae.</td>
      <td>Praesentium.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Possimus?</td>
      <td>Qui.</td>
      <td>Consequuntur.</td>
      <td>Deleniti.</td>
      <td>Voluptas.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Hic?</td>
      <td>Ab.</td>
      <td>Asperiores?</td>
      <td>Omnis.</td>
      <td>Animi!</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cupiditate.</td>
      <td>Velit.</td>
      <td>Libero.</td>
      <td>Iste.</td>
      <td>Dicta?</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Consequatur!</td>
      <td>Nobis.</td>
      <td>Aperiam!</td>
      <td>Odio.</td>
      <td>Nemo!</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Dolorem.</td>
      <td>Distinctio?</td>
      <td>Provident?</td>
      <td>Nisi!</td>
      <td>Impedit?</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Accusantium?</td>
      <td>Ea.</td>
      <td>Doloribus.</td>
      <td>Nobis.</td>
      <td>Maxime?</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Molestiae.</td>
      <td>Rem?</td>
      <td>Enim!</td>
      <td>Maxime?</td>
      <td>Reiciendis!</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Commodi.</td>
      <td>At.</td>
      <td>Earum?</td>
      <td>Fugit.</td>
      <td>Maxime?</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Eligendi?</td>
      <td>Quis.</td>
      <td>Error?</td>
      <td>Atque.</td>
      <td>Perferendis.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Quidem.</td>
      <td>Odit!</td>
      <td>Tempore.</td>
      <td>Voluptates.</td>
      <td>Facere!</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Repudiandae!</td>
      <td>Accusamus?</td>
      <td>Soluta.</td>
      <td>Incidunt.</td>
      <td>Aliquid?</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Quisquam?</td>
      <td>Eius.</td>
      <td>Obcaecati?</td>
      <td>Maxime.</td>
      <td>Nihil.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Minus.</td>
      <td>Magni?</td>
      <td>Necessitatibus?</td>
      <td>Asperiores.</td>
      <td>Iure.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ipsa!</td>
      <td>Temporibus.</td>
      <td>Non!</td>
      <td>Dolore.</td>
      <td>Veritatis.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ea!</td>
      <td>Officia?</td>
      <td>Doloribus?</td>
      <td>Deleniti?</td>
      <td>Dolorem!</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sequi?</td>
      <td>Molestias!</td>
      <td>Nesciunt.</td>
      <td>Qui.</td>
      <td>Doloribus?</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Id.</td>
      <td>Enim?</td>
      <td>Quam!</td>
      <td>Sunt!</td>
      <td>Consequuntur.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Reprehenderit?</td>
      <td>Ut?</td>
      <td>Veritatis!</td>
      <td>Corporis!</td>
      <td>Ipsa.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Blanditiis!</td>
      <td>Veniam!</td>
      <td>Tenetur.</td>
      <td>Eos?</td>
      <td>Repellat!</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Enim?</td>
      <td>Atque!</td>
      <td>Aspernatur?</td>
      <td>Fugit.</td>
      <td>Voluptatibus!</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Nihil.</td>
      <td>Distinctio!</td>
      <td>Aut!</td>
      <td>Rerum!</td>
      <td>Dolorem?</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Inventore!</td>
      <td>Hic.</td>
      <td>Explicabo.</td>
      <td>Sit.</td>
      <td>A.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Inventore.</td>
      <td>A.</td>
      <td>Nam.</td>
      <td>Beatae.</td>
      <td>Consequatur.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Eligendi.</td>
      <td>Illum.</td>
      <td>Enim?</td>
      <td>Dignissimos!</td>
      <td>Ducimus?</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Eligendi!</td>
      <td>Fugiat?</td>
      <td>Deleniti!</td>
      <td>Rerum?</td>
      <td>Delectus?</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sit.</td>
      <td>Nam.</td>
      <td>Eveniet?</td>
      <td>Veritatis.</td>
      <td>Adipisci!</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Nostrum?</td>
      <td>Totam?</td>
      <td>Voluptates!</td>
      <td>Ab!</td>
      <td>Consequatur.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Error!</td>
      <td>Dicta?</td>
      <td>Voluptatum?</td>
      <td>Corporis!</td>
      <td>Ea.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Vel.</td>
      <td>Asperiores.</td>
      <td>Facere.</td>
      <td>Quae.</td>
      <td>Fugiat.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Libero?</td>
      <td>Molestias.</td>
      <td>Praesentium!</td>
      <td>Accusantium!</td>
      <td>Tenetur.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Eveniet.</td>
      <td>Quam.</td>
      <td>Quibusdam.</td>
      <td>Eaque?</td>
      <td>Dolore!</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Asperiores.</td>
      <td>Impedit.</td>
      <td>Ullam?</td>
      <td>Quod.</td>
      <td>Placeat.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>In?</td>
      <td>Aliquid.</td>
      <td>Voluptatum!</td>
      <td>Omnis?</td>
      <td>Magni.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Autem.</td>
      <td>Earum!</td>
      <td>Debitis!</td>
      <td>Eius.</td>
      <td>Incidunt.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Blanditiis?</td>
      <td>Impedit.</td>
      <td>Libero?</td>
      <td>Reiciendis!</td>
      <td>Tempore.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Quasi.</td>
      <td>Reiciendis.</td>
      <td>Aut?</td>
      <td>Architecto?</td>
      <td>Vero!</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Fuga!</td>
      <td>Illum!</td>
      <td>Tenetur!</td>
      <td>Vitae.</td>
      <td>Natus.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Dolorem?</td>
      <td>Eaque!</td>
      <td>Vero?</td>
      <td>Quibusdam.</td>
      <td>Deleniti?</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Minus.</td>
      <td>Accusantium?</td>
      <td>Ab.</td>
      <td>Cupiditate.</td>
      <td>Atque?</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Hic.</td>
      <td>Eligendi.</td>
      <td>Sit?</td>
      <td>Nihil.</td>
      <td>Dolor.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Quidem.</td>
      <td>In?</td>
      <td>Nesciunt?</td>
      <td>Adipisci.</td>
      <td>Neque.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Eos.</td>
      <td>Incidunt!</td>
      <td>Quis?</td>
      <td>Quod?</td>
      <td>Vitae!</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ullam!</td>
      <td>Facilis.</td>
      <td>Tempora!</td>
      <td>Accusantium.</td>
      <td>Consequuntur?</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Numquam?</td>
      <td>At.</td>
      <td>Incidunt.</td>
      <td>Tenetur?</td>
      <td>Voluptatem.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Iusto?</td>
      <td>Inventore.</td>
      <td>Molestias.</td>
      <td>Accusantium.</td>
      <td>Sunt.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Repellendus!</td>
      <td>Ex.</td>
      <td>Magnam.</td>
      <td>Odit!</td>
      <td>Iste?</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Id!</td>
      <td>Reiciendis?</td>
      <td>Rem.</td>
      <td>Quae!</td>
      <td>Laborum?</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Exercitationem?</td>
      <td>Maiores.</td>
      <td>Minima.</td>
      <td>Nemo!</td>
      <td>Sequi.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Qui.</td>
      <td>Impedit?</td>
      <td>Reprehenderit.</td>
      <td>Distinctio.</td>
      <td>Natus?</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Suscipit!</td>
      <td>Tenetur.</td>
      <td>Cumque!</td>
      <td>Molestiae.</td>
      <td>Fugiat?</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sunt?</td>
      <td>Quis?</td>
      <td>Officia.</td>
      <td>Incidunt.</td>
      <td>Voluptate.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Possimus.</td>
      <td>Mollitia!</td>
      <td>Eveniet!</td>
      <td>Temporibus.</td>
      <td>Mollitia!</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Incidunt.</td>
      <td>Fugiat.</td>
      <td>Error.</td>
      <td>Odit.</td>
      <td>Cumque?</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Maxime?</td>
      <td>Qui!</td>
      <td>Sapiente!</td>
      <td>Natus.</td>
      <td>Soluta?</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```